# Android: barecode scanner is crash when application starts

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I trying to write a bare-code scanner application. I found this [video][1] on YouTube that explain very well. I have done exactly what is in this video, but When I compile, the app crashes. I have try to find the error on google, but  I have no solution. I have tried few things like

```
File -> Invalidate Cache and restart
```

but still not working.

I am new in android. can you please help me with this ?

here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.noums.qrcodereader"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
```

In the build.gradle file I have this error:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
here is my run log:

```
  10/13 02:51:52: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/dep/dependencies.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_6.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_0.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_1.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_4.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_8.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/resources/instant-run/debug/resources-debug.apk /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/QRcodeReader/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-apk/debug/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 4 s 491 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.noums.qrcodereader/com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 31525 on device oneplus-oneplus_a5010-d3691788
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/zygote64: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcode
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcode
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcodereader-9oqdGKRhlKrW2VVgy_xxtA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.noums.qrcode
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.noums.qrcodereader, PID: 31525
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noums.qrcodereader/com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2911)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7041)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
W/OPDiagnose: getService:OPDiagnoseService NULL
D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
D/AbstractTracker: Event success
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please downgrade to code in below comment and say what happened

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.noums.qrcodereader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
```

That looks like a null reference on line 50 of your MainActivity.java file.